# 'reCAPTCHA:ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key' error coming when I get website using Requests in python. How to login?

Tags: python, python-requests, recaptcha

[image: response of get request using Requests library in python]

I want to login to `https://student.amizone.net` using Requests library in python but I am getting the error `ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key` this error does not show when I open website through browser. How can I login?
this is my python code, that I have tried:

```
import requests
login_data = {
'_UserName': 'username',
'_Password': 'password'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://student.amizone.net'
    r1 = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    r2 = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers = headers)
    print(r1.text)
```

I have also tried: `r1 = s.get(url, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'))` but got the same result(didn't login)

this is the response `r1.text` that i'm getting:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Amizone</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/login-files/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="/Content/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
        @media(min-width:991px){
            .login100-form {
            left:420px;


            }
            .login100-pic {
            right:420px;

            }

        }



    </style>


</head>

<body>





    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <div class="logo-section">

                    <img src="/login-files/amizone-logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="widget-box login-box visible login100-form" id="login-box">
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        LOGIN  <small> Student | Parent </small><br clear="all" />
                        <span>
                            <a href="https://amizone.net/adminamizone/index.aspx">
                                <b style="color:blue;">
                                    Click here for admin login
                                </b>
                            </a>
                        </span>

                    </span>

<form action="/Login/Login" class=" validate-form" id="loginform" method="post" name="loginform">                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="User Name is required">
                            <input autocomplete="off" class=" input100" data-val="true" data-val-required="User Name is required !!" name="_UserName" placeholder="User Name" type="text" value="" />


                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                            <input autocomplete="off" class=" input100" data-val="true" data-val-length="Must be between 5 and 20 characters" data-val-length-max="20" data-val-length-min="5" data-val-required="Password is required !!" name="_Password" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-input100">


                        </div>
                        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-t-12 fg-password">
                            <span class="txt1">
                                Forgot
                            </span>
                            <a href="#" class="txt2" data-target="#forgot-box">
                                Username / Password?
                            </a>
                        </div>
</form>                </div>
                <div class="widget-box forgot-box login100-form" id="forgot-box">
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        Password Recovery
                    </span>
<form action="/Login/ForgotPassword" class=" validate-form" id="ForgetForm" method="post" name="ForgetForm"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CIu-qUEXGRgcyZkrrLhEbz-8rIxUM2Vj8bZTqFeP96KoaLdnAX_COKuwy-6vm_HHZTdZd8dUCylFh8_Y5aWNJiJSD0RlGZgSz3i6yMPvWSQ1" />                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="User Name is required">
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="input100" data-val="true" data-val-required="User Name is required !!" name="_UserName" placeholder="User Name" type="text" value="" />
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                            <span class="symbol-input100">
                                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-input100">
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfVOEcUAAAAAFa_lQg8WJ-e_5qYNDnlmxSXL05S"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">Get Password</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center p-t-12 fg-password">
                            <span class="txt1">
                                Back
                            </span>
                            <a href="#" class="txt2" data-target="#login-box">
                                Login
                            </a>
                        </div>
</form>                </div>

                <div class="login100-pic">

                    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">




                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="https://www.amity.edu/asfd/" target="_blank">
                                <img src='/login-files/amizonedrama.jpg' data-zoom-image='/login-files/amizonedrama.jpg'>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="https://amity.edu/amimun/" target="_blank">
                                <img src='/login-files/AMIMUN20.jpg' data-zoom-image='/login-files/AMIMUN20.jpg'>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">

                            <a href="http://amityfinishingschool.com" target="_blank">

                                <img src='/login-files/QSRanking.jpg' data-zoom-image='/login-files/QSRanking.jpg'>

                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>






            </div>
        </div>

    </div>




    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script src="/login-files/jquery.elevatezoom.js"></script>
    <script src="/login-files/main.js"></script>

    <!-- include the style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/alertifyjs/alertify.min.css" />
    <!-- include a theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/alertifyjs/themes/default.min.css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/alertify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

            navigation: false, // Show next and prev buttons
            slideSpeed: 300,
            paginationSpeed: 400,
            singleItem: true,
            autoPlay: 3000,



        });

        jQuery(function ($) {
            $(document).on('click', '.fg-password a[data-target]', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var target = $(this).data('target');
                $('.widget-box.visible').removeClass('visible');//hide others
                $(target).addClass('visible');//show target
            });
        });



    </script>
    <script>

        $(".rank-image").elevateZoom({ constrainType: "height", constrainSize: 274, zoomType: "lens", lensShape: "round", lensSize: 100, containLensZoom: true, gallery: 'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: "active" });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

`r2.text` is the same.

this is how the site looks in the browser, it shows no reCAPTCHA:
[image]

Comment: you should remove the username/password although at this point it has been visible for too long. I would change my password now if I was you

Comment: also none of your attempts use [auth](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/) as shown in the docs, please try those as well

Comment: @aws_apprentice I just tried that too but it didn't work. i have edited.

Comment: Google Captchas wont work with requests, you need to use Selenium, Puppeteer, ...

Comment: @MauriceMeyer when i load the website in browser it doesn't ask for reCAPTCHA. so the browser essentially is sending HTTP requests which should work with python-requests too i think.

Comment: No, you are missing two things. First, in browsers Javascript is executed, which is not done with any HTTP library. You can see in the [recaptcha docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) there is more or less just one Javascript file integrated that does all the 'magic'. Second, isnt that the reason why people use any kind of captchas ? Like preventing (bot-)automation, copying/stealing information ...